# Why is my WCF client's binding settings are not working?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I am calling a WCF service from some stub. The issue is that, I can not have the `app.config` on the client side. So I am setting the values from within my code.

The service `web.config` shows values like this:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
       <basicHttpBinding>
         <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IStatementsManagerService" openTimeout="00:10:00" 
                closeTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="true" 
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="567890" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="567890"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                          maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
           <!--<security mode="None">
             <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                 realm="" />
             <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
           </security>-->
         </binding>
       </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="PathFINDER.Services.IStatementsManagerService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IStatementsManagerService"
                contract="PopulateReqProServiceERReqs.IStatementsManagerService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IStatementsManagerService" />
            <endpoint kind="mexEndpoint" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

And the code on the client side is like this:

```
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            //System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
            binding.Name = "BasicHttpBinding_IStatementsManagerService";
            binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 01, 00);
            binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 01, 00);
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 10, 00);
            binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(00, 10, 00);

            binding.AllowCookies = false;
            binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
            binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
            binding.MaxBufferSize = 567890;
            binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 567890;
            binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
            //binding.TextEncoding= "utf-8";
            binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
            binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;

            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth=2147483647;
            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength=2147483647;
            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength=2147483647;
            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead=2147483647;
            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount=2147483647; 

            string ServiceUrl = "http://localhost:56620/StatementsManagerService.svc";
            System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(ServiceUrl);
            PopulateReqProService.StatementsManagerServiceClient Smsc = new PopulateReqProService.StatementsManagerServiceClient(binding, remoteAddress);
            blnReturn = Smsc.MyMethod(MyParam);
```

But the issue is that when I call the service with lots of data in the parameter, it fails with a protocoleception and in the svclog file I can clearly see the exception as:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has
>   been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property on the appropriate binding element.

Can somebody help? I am not getting any clue.

Comment: I have also updated the client code for the ReaderQuotas. However that is not giving any positive result.

Comment: You've set MaxReceivedMessageSize to 567890 which is roughly 560 KB. What's the size of the message you are sending ? You can get the apprx size of the message with a tool like fiddler.

Comment: The size of the message is roughly 150 kB. But what worries me is the message in the exception. It is still showing me the default value. And this is what is my concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to set the values (on your client side `binding` in code) that you specify in the `<ReaderQuotas>` section of your `web.config`!

```
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;
```

then it should work:

Comment: I tried setting the ReaderQuotas in the client code as well. But not getting any good result so far.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to increase the MaxReceivedMessageSize property as the method you are calling is returning data with a length greater than 567890. Just experiment with the values on both the server and the client.

Comment: I have already spent quality time with a good duration trying to figure out with lots of experiments. I wish to have answers that can guide me to the resolution. If you see the exception, what I am seeing is that the value for the MaxReceivedMessageSize is still the default one and the override in the code is probably nont working. Here I am concerned.

Comment: You need to increase MaxReceivedMessageSize on both client and server.

Comment: @Bahri Gungor: If you look at the post carefully, you should be able to see the same values in the both sides; in the web.config on the server side, and in the code in the client side.

Comment: @Kangkan You've got the MaxReceivedMessageSize set at 567890. The likelihood is that you're exceeding that value. Set it to something like 2048000000 and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: @Chris Pont: You should read the prime concern in the post. Look at the exception message and it seems that the updated value of MaxReceivedMessageSize set at 567890 is also not working. BTW, the load is hardly 150 kB as of now and the value set is quite sufficient. I also tried setting a 10 digit number earlier. It is not working and I am getting the same error.

Comment: @Kangkan: MaxReceivedMessageSize is the entire size of the message, not just your parameter. What is in MyParam?

Comment: @Bahri Gungor: I understand this and the message size is still below 150kB when I check it with Fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

In behavior, you will need to set this, try below code:

```
maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"
```

I know this is very old question, but still.